# es6 not working in yeoman generator gulp-webapp

Tags: gulp, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I updated the generator-gulp-webapp and gulp and I'm trying to use a freshly scaffolded project.

When I try to use es6 I'm just getting an error in the console. It's just a basic check for functionality.

```
let test = () => console.log('test');

test();
```

The gulpfile works fine which is written in es6. It's loading `babel-core/register` when I run gulp commands.

I am using atom and have `language-babel` package installed, otherwise no other modifications have been done, and nothing is installed in this project.

I've tried starting my `main.js` file with combinations of `"use strict";` and `"use babel";` with no success either.

I tried changing the file extension to `main.babel.js` and updated that in the html file also, but that also made no difference.

I'm sure it's something trivial I'm missing, but I can't see the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There's a big difference between writing your app code and your Gulpfile.js with es6.

The thing is that one is going to run into your browser and the other is runned by node.

When running code in browser, that code needs to be pre-compiled. When running in Node, babel will usually hijack `require` calls and pre-compile your code on the fly.

My guess is that you're not running the pre-compilation on your browser code before trying to serve it.

Also, please refer to Babel documentation. There's no `"use babel"` or `filename.babel.js` magic.